# How to get SSAS tabular model attributes and dimensions usage details

Tags: ssas, sql-server-profiler, ssas-tabular, dmv

I need to create a cube which purpose would be to gather detailed information about tabular model dimensions and attributes usage by users (e.g. how many times users access certain dimension).
So far, I tried to use Data Management View Query (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230820.aspx) and SQLProfiler and I could see which commands were executed in a session.
I wonder if there is any way to get the number of dimensions/attributes usage without parsing the commands.
Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to monitor all queries sent to an analysis services (tabular) instance by setting up Extended Events.

You can set up an extended event on your analysis services instance through SQL Server Management Studio by navigating to Management-->Extended Events-->Sessions, and then right clicking and selecting "New session...".

You can set up your extended events session to catch specific event types, such as "QueryBegin" and "QueryEnd". This will log all QueryBegin and QueryEnd events to a log file on the path you've specified. In the log files created by the extended event you will then be able to find information about all queries that have hit the analysis services instance.

With a bit of work you should be able to create a cube that shows how many queries have hit a certain dimension, how many queries have been sent by a certain user, etc.